# Swift - Why i can't change my tint color when i select?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I'm new to swift do you guys have any suggestions and here is my code,
and i couldn't change the tint color on my Tab Bar.

```
let myTabBar = UITabBar()

myTabBar.tintColor = UIColor.green

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
   myTabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red
}

let one = UITabBarItem()
    one.title = "Home"
    one.tag = 1
    one.image = UIImage(named: "home")

    myTabBar.delegate = self

 func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    switch item.tag {
    case 1:
        let controller = businessStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BusinessListViewController")
        addChildViewController(controller)
        view.addSubview((controller.view)!)
        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: I couldn't change the tint color on my Tab Bar.

Actually, your code looks fine on the tint color change, but it is not called when tab bar is selected.

You need to call method to change your tab bar tint color inside your on select method

Comment: do you have an example i tried a few ways it doesn't works.